# laravel prevent go back after order placed in ecommerce

Tags: php, laravel, e-commerce

How to prevent Laravel page from going back after order placed to not make a double payment. I've got many related answers but none of them work with me.

I've tried makeing a middleware class and call header code

and called it from route file

```php
return $response->header('Cache-Control','no-store, nocache, no-store, max-age=0, must-revalidate')
->header('Pragma','no-cache')
->header('Expires','Sun, 02 Jan 1990 00:00:00 GMT')
->header('Cache-Control',' post-check=0, pre-check=0, false');
```

and then I've called the class in route like this:

```php
Route::group(['middleware' => 'prevent-order-back'],function(){
        Auth::routes();
        //Route::get('/home', 'HomeController@index');
        Route::post('/place_order', 'OrdersController@place_order');
    });
```

I'm using Laravel 5.5

Comment: Use the session to store/check if an order has been placed recently, check for orders from the customer's address in the past X minutes...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding the following after the the code in the place_order function in the OrdersController might solve your problem:
`return redirect(view('<path to order placed page or index>'))`.
using a redirect from the controller prevents the browser from sending the data again.
more info about how to implement the redirects is available in the [Laravel documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/redirects)

Comment: Thank you for reply. I have a redirect function already there, But Problem not solved.->     return redirect('orders')->with('success', Lang::get("website.Payment has been processed successfully"));
  }else if($payment_status == "failed"){
   return redirect()->back()->with('error', Lang::get("website.Error while placing order"));  
  }

Answer (score 0):

I did some more searching (stripe api) and found that you could use something callend an idempotent request to fix the double payment issue. I've found [a laravel library](https://packagist.org/packages/javidalpe/laravel-idempotency) which handles this through middleware.

It's basically sending an (user)unique key and stores the response in cache, the browser wil send the cached reponse if the same (user)unique key is used in the following 24 hours.